# Problem with passing component props to a component built with LoadingButton MUI

Tags: typescript, material-ui

This is my component built with LoadingButton MUI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYpM8.png)

And I can't passing my component props:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZJ6F.png)

I am getting a typescript problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKwQA.png)

I can fix it with assertions but maybe it can be done better?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please share code, errors and log as text (may inside code fences) and not with images. It is easier to read and help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because the type for the `LoadingButtonProps` provided to `forwardRef` is incorrect. Here's one way to fix this -

`AppButton.ts`

```js
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import {ButtonBaseProps} from "@mui/material/ButtonBase";
import { LoadingButton, LoadingButtonProps, LoadingButtonTypeMap } from "@mui/lab";

const AppButton = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, LoadingButtonProps<LoadingButtonTypeMap['defaultComponent'],{component: ButtonBaseProps["component"]}>>((props, ref) => {
  return <LoadingButton {...props} ref={ref}></LoadingButton>

});

export default AppButton;
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-yalow-7kp88l) example.